# Need to convert the array of filepaths into treeview json object

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

Need to convert the array of file paths into Treeview JSON object

Array Data:

```
[path1/subpath1/file1.doc",
"path1/subpath1/file2.doc", 
"path1/subpath2/file1.doc", 
"path1/subpath2/file2.doc", 
"path2/subpath1/file1.doc", 
"path2/subpath1/file2.doc", 
"path2/subpath2/file1.doc", 
"path2/subpath2/file2.doc", 
"path2/subpath2/additionalpath1/file1.doc"]
```

I want below object Result:

```
{
   "title": "path1",
   "childNodes" : [
     { "title":"subpath1", "childNodes":[{ "title":"file1.doc", "childNodes":[] }] },
     { "title":"subpath2", "childNodes":[{ "title":"file1.doc", "childNodes":[] }] }
   ] 
}
```

I was able to convert it into an object using the below code snippet but not able to transform the way I want it

```
let treePath = {};
let formattedData = {};
data.forEach(path => {
  let levels = path.split("/");
  let file = levels.pop();
  let prevLevel = treePath;
  let prevProp = levels.shift();
  levels.forEach(prop => {
    prevLevel[prevProp] = prevLevel[prevProp] || {};
    prevLevel = prevLevel[prevProp];
    prevProp = prop;
  });
  prevLevel[prevProp] = (prevLevel[prevProp] || []).concat([file]);
});
```

How can i do this????

Comment: Your array was not valid. Missing quote

Comment: @mplungjan, thanks for the edit

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the parts of pathes and search for same title.

```js
const
    pathes = ["path1/subpath1/file1.doc", "path1/subpath1/file2.doc", "path1/subpath2/file1.doc", "path1/subpath2/file2.doc", "path2/subpath1/file1.doc", "path2/subpath1/file2.doc", "path2/subpath2/file1.doc", "path2/subpath2/file2.doc", "path2/subpath2/additionalpath1/file1.doc"],
    result = pathes.reduce((r, path) => {
        path.split('/').reduce((childNodes, title) => {
            let child = childNodes.find(n => n.title === title);
            if (!child) childNodes.push(child = { title, childNodes: [] });
            return child.childNodes;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can we add a level (its respective) at each node?

Comment: shure, you could add `level` to `(childNodes, title, level) =>` and use it here `child = { title, level, `. if you need level from one, you need to add one.